# Regex: Negative lookahead after list match

Tags: regex

Consider the following input string (part of `css` file):

```
url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...');
url(example.png);
```

The objective is to take the url part using regex and do something with it. So the first part is easy:

```
url\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\)
```

Basically, it takes contents from inside `url(...)` with optional quotes symbols. Using this regexp I get the following matches:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...
example.png
```

So far so good. Now I want to exclude the urls which include 'data:image' in their text. I think negative lookahead is the proper tool for that but using it like this:

```
url\(['"]?(?!data:image)(.+?)['"]?\)
```

gives me the following result for the first url:

```
'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...
```

Not only it doesn't exclude this match, but the matched string itself now includes quote character at the beginning. If I use `+` instead of first `?` like this:

```
url\(['"]+(?!data:image)(.+?)['"]?\)
```

it works as expected, url is not matched. But this doesn't allow the optional quote in url (since `+` is 1 or more). How should I change the regex to exclude given url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead like this:

```
url\((['"]?)((?:(?!data:image).)+?)\1?\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uR3oZ9/1)